# Bring back DbContext.Detach() method with an extension method (EF5)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

There is no `Detach(object entity)` on the `DbContext` in Entity Framework 5.

To detach an entity, the state now needs to be changed.  Maybe I am missing something, but this seems much less intuitive and readable than using the `Detach` method:

```
context.Entry(myEntity).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

I am tempted to just create an extension method to bring back the Detach method:

```
public static void Detach(this MyEntities context, object entity)
{
    context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;
}
```

**What is the reason why Microsoft removed the DbContext.Detach() method in EF 5?**

Comment: "I am tempted to just create an extension method" -- Why would you create an extension method for a class you have full control over? You can add it to `WIMTEntities` directly.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Removing a `Detach` method from the (`DbContext`) API has some logic because `Detach` doesn't operate on an object graph but it only detaches the single object that you pass into the method. This is different to all other methods that change the object state:

- `Attach` attaches the supplied object including all related objects in the object graph of navigation properties
- `Add` adds the supplied object including all related objects to the context
- `Remove` deletes the supplied object including the related objects that have been configured with cascading delete

On the other hand setting the state manually to `Modified`, `Added` or `Deleted` always only acts on the supplied object, not on the related objects. This is also the case for calling the `Detach` method of `ObjectContext`. It is more consequent to detach an object only via setting the state to `Detached` to be in line with the behaviour of other state changes because like setting any other state it only influences the supplied object without related objects.

`DbContext` is - among other features - intended to make working with Entity Framework easier. The old `Detach` method was more confusing and its behaviour is not like many developers expect. ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10343174/270591) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7693732/270591) are two references about this confusion and the complexities involved in detaching an object.) In my opinion it wasn't the wrong step to remove it from the `DbContext` API.

Well, you can always write you own extension method like you did or access the underlying `ObjectContext` via the adapter if you really want to have a `Detach` method.

Answer (score 5):

I've no idea why there is no `Detach()` method but the `DbSet` class exposes a method `AsNoTracking()` to fetch objects that are detached from the `DbContext`.

Here's some example code from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/02/05/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-11-load-and-asnotracking.aspx)

```
using (var context = new UnicornsContext())
{
    // Query for all unicorns without tracking them
    var unicorns1 = context.Unicorns.AsNoTracking();

    // Query for some unitcorns without tracking them
    var unicorns2 = context.Unicorns
        .Where(u => u.Name.EndsWith("ky"))
        .AsNoTracking()
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Noting [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5600202/538763) indicates that AsNoTracking may not be equivalent to Detach.