# How to combine Find() and AsNoTracking()?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How to combine `Find()` with `AsNoTracking()` when making queries to an EF context to prevent the returned object from being tracked. This is what I can't do

```
 _context.Set<Entity>().AsNoTracking().Find(id);
```

How can I do that? I am using EF version 6.

Note: I do not want to use `SingleOrDefault()`, or `Where`. I just can't because the parameter `Id` is generic and it's a `struct` and I can not apply operator `==` for generics in that case.

Comment: "*I just can't*" is not an enforcable claim unless you can show us why you  can't.  Given the knowledge of the SO community, perhaps you can, you just don't know **how**.

Comment: @Tommy thanks, added more details.

Comment: You should be able to use `Equals` rather than using `==` if that's your only problem, but I suspect there will also be some other problems that you're not sharing in your question yet: there's no standard way of extracting an entity's key properties, for instance.

Comment: @hvd Equals does not translate as well, the error I got was: "Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context"

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis Some overloads of `Equals` aren't supported, others are.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @Derked nope, I ended up overriding every get method in my repositories..

Comment: Internally EF Core uses a support class `IEntityFinder` (see https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/0103866b680b626813d0e2a258b62d0551e6fea6/src/EFCore/Internal/InternalDbSet.cs#L429) to build the where expression. This interface also has a `Query` method. Pity it's internal, or I'd suggest using that.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

So instead of using `AsNoTracking()` what you can do is `Find()` and then detach it from the context. I believe that this gives you the same result as `AsNoTracking()` besides the additional overhead of getting the entity tracked. See [EntityState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entitystate(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.

```
var entity = Context.Set<T>().Find(id);
Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;
return entity;
```

Edit: This has some potential issues, if the context hasn't loaded some relationships, then those navigation properties will not work and you will be confused and frustrated why everything is returning null! See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10343174/2558743 for more info. For now on those repositories I'm overriding the `FindNoTracking()` methods in my repositories that I need that in.

Comment: Rosedi Kasim should be the correct answer. Read the documentation and it just doesn't make sense to use Find with AsNoTracking https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/ You may as well find an entity using a query.

Comment: If you read the note on the question, Rosedi Kasim's answer is not sufficient when using generics since you can't use the == operator so it won't even compile.

Comment: You can eager load navigation properties before detaching the entity. 
Pass inn a params array of Expression<Func<TEnttiy, object>>[] of navigationproperties and then just use the Include method to include the navigation property in a foreach. And starting with IQueryable<T> query = dbContext.Set<T>();  Then you will not have null values in the navigation properties. Do this before you detach. Great answer by the way.

Answer (score 32):

```
<context>.<Entity>.AsNoTracking().Where(s => s.Id == id);
```

`Find()` does not make sense with `AsNoTracking()` because `Find` is supposed to be able to return tracked entities without going to database.. your only option with `AsNoTracking` is either `Where` or `First` or `Single...`

Comment: Can't use that, because the `Id` is generic and I can not use the operator `==` with generics :)

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis Can  you show your full code snippet why generic can't work in this case?

Comment: check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390900/cant-operator-be-applied-to-generic-types-in-c), for me the TKey is struct type. So, I jsut can't.

Comment: I suspect there is a way to work around that.. but without a sample code I can't help much since I do not know your actual situation.. if you add some code I am sure someone could show you some workaround...

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Read the documentation and it just doesn't make sense to use Find with AsNoTracking https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/

Comment: This is the correct answer. Make use of the Base class for EF models and reflection.

Answer (score 9):

Back in 2015, an [official request was made to include the functionality](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/2533), i.e. combine Find() and AsNoTracking(). The issue was immediately closed after giving this argument:

> `AsNoTracking` doesn't really make sense for `Find` since one of the key features of find is that it will return the already tracked version of the entity without hitting the database if it is already in memory. If you want to load an entity by key without tracking it then use `Single`.

Hence, you could replace:

```
_context.Set<Entity>().AsNoTracking().Find(id); // Invalid
```

with something like this:

```
_context.Set<Entity>().AsNoTracking().Single(e => e.Id == id);
```

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer has the issue that if the item you are trying to find is already being tracked, it will return that item then mark it as untracked (which may mess up other parts of the code).

Akos is on the right track with his suggestion to build the expression yourself, but the example only works for entities that have a single primary key (which covers most cases).

This extension method works in EF Core and effectively matches the signature for the `DbSet<T>.Find(object [])`. But it is an extension method for `DbContext` instead of `DbSet` because it needs access to the Entity's metadata from the DbContext.

```
public static T FindNoTracking<T>(this DbContext source, params object[] keyValues)
    where T : class
{
    DbSet<T> set = source.Set<T>();
    if (keyValues == null || !keyValues.Any())
    {
        throw new Exception("No Keys Provided.");
    }

    PropertyInfo[] keyProps = GetKeyProperties<T>(source);
    if (keyProps.Count() != keyValues.Count())
    {
        throw new Exception("Incorrect Number of Keys Provided.");
    }

    ParameterExpression prm = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    Expression body = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < keyProps.Count(); i++)
    {
        PropertyInfo pi = keyProps[i];
        object value = keyValues[i];
        Expression propertyEx = Expression.Property(prm, pi);
        Expression valueEx = Expression.Constant(value);
        Expression condition = Expression.Equal(propertyEx, valueEx);
        body = body == null ? condition : Expression.AndAlso(body, condition);
    }

    var filter = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, prm);
    return set.AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefault(filter);
}

public static PropertyInfo[] GetKeyProperties<T>(this DbContext source)
{
    return source.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(T)).FindPrimaryKey().Properties.Select(p => p.PropertyInfo).ToArray();
}
```

you can then use the method directly on the DbContext. For example, if your entity has a composite key consisting of two strings:

```
context.FindNoTracking<MyEntity>("Key Value 1", "Key Value 2");
```

If you really want the Extension method to be on `DbSet` instead of the `DbContext`, you can do so but you'll need to get the context from the set in order to gain access to the metadata about the entity. Currently there isn't a good way to do this.  [There are some hacky ways to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710769/can-you-get-the-dbcontext-from-a-dbset), but they involve using reflection to access private fields of framework classes, so I'd advise against it.

---

*Alternatively...*

If you have a way of figure out what the Key properties are without using the DbContext/Metadata, you can make it an extension for `DbSet` instead. For example, if all of your Key properties are marked with the `[Key]` attribute, you can use this code:

```
public static T FindNoTracking<T>(this DbSet<T> source, params object[] keyValues)
    where T : class
{
    //Pretty much the same...
}

public static PropertyInfo[] GetKeyProperties<T>()
{
    return typeof(T).GetProperties()
        .Where(pi => pi.GetCustomAttribute<KeyAttribute>() != null).ToArray();
}
```

This would also work in both Entity Framework and EF Core.

Answer (score 2):

In asp net core 7 you can disable tracking when you want to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking#no-tracking-queries:

```cs
context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;

var product = await context.Products.FindAsync(id);
```

Comment: is it possible to change the tracking behavior , select the data, and then enable it without affecting any of the objects already being tracked?

Comment: The Find method actually doesn't fully respect the QueryTrackingBehavior. You will receive a tracked record if the record you request is already tracked by the context!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess if you really want to do this, you can try creating your expression yourself. I assume you have a base entity class that's generic and that's where the generic key property comes from. I named that class `KeyedEntityBase<TKey>`, `TKey` is the type of the key (if you don't have such a class, that's fine, the only thing that I used that for is the generic constraint). Then you can create an extension method like this to build the expression yourself:

```
public static class Extensions
{
   public static IQueryable<TEntity> WhereIdEquals<TEntity, TKey>(
            this IQueryable<TEntity> source,
            Expression<Func<TEntity, TKey>> keyExpression,
            TKey otherKeyValue)
            where TEntity : KeyedEntityBase<TKey>
  {
    var memberExpression = (MemberExpression)keyExpression.Body; 
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "x"); 
    var property = Expression.Property(parameter, memberExpression.Member.Name); 
    var equal = Expression.Equal(property, Expression.Constant(otherKeyValue));  
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(equal, parameter);
    return source.Where(lambda);
  }
}
```

And then, you can use it like this (for an integer key type):

```
context.Set<MyEntity>.AsNoTracking().WhereIdEquals(m=>m.Id, 9).ToList();
```