# ASP.NET MVC JQUERY Attaching an entity of type failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to do an action with jquery when on button press it changes a value in that database.

My code:

The button:

```
<a class="fa fa-2x fa-check confirmAnswer" href="#" onclick="Confirm(@item.ID)"></a>
```

JS:

```
    var Confirm = function (solutionID) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Help/ConfirmSolution",
        data: { id: solutionID },
        success: function (response) {
            alert("Survey Deleted");
            location.reload();
        },

    })
}
```

Controller Action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult ConfirmSolution(int id)
    {
        HelpSolutionViewModel answer = Mapper.Map<HelpSolution, HelpSolutionViewModel>(unitOfWork.HelpSolutionRepository.GetByID(id));
        answer.Selected = true;
        HelpSolution helpsolution = Mapper.Map<HelpSolutionViewModel, HelpSolution>(answer);
        unitOfWork.HelpSolutionRepository.Update(helpsolution);
        unitOfWork.Save();
        return Json(helpsolution, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Repository methods:

```
        public virtual void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate)
    {
        dbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
        context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public virtual TEntity GetByID(object id)
    {
        return dbSet.Find(id);
    }
```

The error:

> Attaching an entity of type failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key valuelockquote

By the way, the other fixes on the similar questions I saw don't help, I tried loads.

Comment: Can you show the code for `unitOfWork.HelpSolutionRepository.GetByID(id)`?

Comment: sure, I added it @Jerodev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Entity Framework tracks all objects that are fetched from the database. So, in your `GetById` method, you are attaching the object with that id to the entity framework tracker. In your The update method tries to add this object to entity framework again while an object with the same id is already tracked.

A solution for this would be to add [`AsNoTracking`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352(v=vs.103).aspx) to your `GetById` method. This will still return the object but entity framework will not track this object.

Comment: return dbSet.AsNoTracking.Find(id); gives this error "DbQuery<TEntity>.AsNoTracking()" is a method, which is not valid in the given context

Comment: This describes how to use `Find(id)` without tracking: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46223929/743016

Comment: Thanks, this works, but the method overloads almost most of the project, because I use the regular Find where I don't need detaching. So I created a new method GetByID using that. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you attach an already attached Entry to the dbSet.
Try to remove this line:

```
dbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this `Update` method call at all, and all these mapping actions are redundant as well.

You're fetching an object from the database. That object is attached, so you can just modify it and save it.

```
var helpsolution = unitOfWork.HelpSolutionRepository.GetByID(id);
helpsolution.Selected = true;
unitOfWork.Save();
```

This emits an `UPDATE` statement that only updates one field [instead of all fields](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30824229/861716).