Using .NET 8 with EF Core and Identity. Which DbContext does UserManagerUse? Strange error with UserManager
I have a Blazor project that was originally written for .NET 6 and used WebAssembly.
I have migrated it to .NET 8 - still with WebAssembly, but have resolved to move a lot of my 'Admin' functions back to the server using the new 'InteractiveServer' render mode. Which will suit and works great.
I have a bunch of services that interact with the server (standard controllers) but to make this work correctly for BOTH Interactive server and webassembly, it was necessary to make the services into Interfaces and have similar (interface) services on the server that bypass the controller going direct to the data access layer.
I have made this work mostly. But one of the things I had to do was to convert the application DbContext to use the DbContextFactory. This is well described in various Blazor posts on this and other blogs. To avoid errors like this:

A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext

I am now getting EF Core tracking errors like this:

The instance of entity type 'ApplicationUser' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values

The strange thing is I am calling the DAL from the service as follows:
// NOW CHANGED SEE *EDIT* BELOW
public async Task<ApplicationUserDTO> UpdateUser(ApplicationUserDTO user)
{
    using var _dbContext = _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext();

    bool updatingcurrrentuser = false;

    if (user.Id == CurrentUser.Id) 
        updatingcurrrentuser = true;

    InfoBool? result = new();
    bool userisAdmin = false;

    ApplicationUser? loggedinUser = await _userLib.GetLoggedInUser(_dbContext);

    if (_userLib.UserIsAdmin(loggedinUser))
    {
        userisAdmin = true; // This is to allow admin users to add paper tickets which can override the ticket price check
    }

    if (userisAdmin || (user.Id == loggedinUser.Id)) // If the logged in user is an admin or the person edited then allow the update
    {
        // ApplicationUser sentUser = new ApplicationUser();
        // _mapper.Map(sentUserDTO, sentUser);
        result = await _userLib.UpdateUser(_userManager, _dbContext, user, user.Roles, userisAdmin);
    }

    // ... more stuff
}

The UpdateUser function is quite big but handles a lot of stuff:
public async Task<InfoBool> UpdateUser(
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
            RGDbContext context,
            ApplicationUserDTO user,
            List<string> Roles = null,
            bool userisadmin = false)
{
    // First check if its there
    // ApplicationUser founduser = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(user.UserName);

    ApplicationUser? founduser = await context.Users
                                              .Include(x => x.Address)
                                              //.Include(x => x.Player)  // Don't need the player
                                              //.ThenInclude(y => y.Coins)
                                              .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.UserName == user.UserName);

    if (founduser == null)
    {
        return new InfoBool(false, "User to update not found");
    }

    if (founduser.Address != null && user.Address != null && user.Address.Id == 0)
    {
        // If there is an address but the client sends it with a zero id  - to detect a client error
        return new InfoBool(false, "Address Id mismatch Error");
    }

    _mapper.Map(user, founduser);
    _mapper.Map(user.Address, founduser.Address);

    IList<string> currentroles = await GetRolesAsync(context, founduser.Id);

    // First check for changed roles
    // Creates a list of the roles in Roles to add not in current roles
    List<string> newrolestoadd = Roles.Except(currentroles).ToList();

    // Create a list of the roles in current roles to remove not in roles
    List<string> rolestoremove = currentroles.Except(Roles).ToList();

    if (newrolestoadd.Count() > 0) // There are some 
    {
        // If a player role has been added
        if (!currentroles.Contains(Enums.AllowedRoles.Player.ToString())
            && Roles.Contains(Enums.AllowedRoles.Player.ToString()))
        {
            founduser.IsPlayer = true;
        }

        if (!userisadmin && newrolestoadd.Contains(Enums.AllowedRoles.Administrator.ToString()))
        { 
            // Just a check that any user adding an adminrole is already an admin
            newrolestoadd.Remove(Enums.AllowedRoles.Administrator.ToString()); //Not allowed
            // TODO: add a log record here to indicate a possible security risk
        }

        await AddUsertoRoles(userManager, founduser, newrolestoadd);
    }

    // Remove roles
    if (rolestoremove.Count() > 0)
    {
        if (!userisadmin && rolestoremove.Contains(Enums.AllowedRoles.Administrator.ToString()))
        { 
            // Only an admin can remove an admin
            rolestoremove.Remove(Enums.AllowedRoles.Administrator.ToString());
        }

        await RemoveUserFromRoles(userManager, founduser, rolestoremove);
    }

    // Now check the address (we don't check for changes IN the address, just if it exists.
    try
    {
        context.Entry(founduser).State = EntityState.Modified;
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return new InfoBool(false, e.Message);
    }

    return new InfoBool(true, "User update successful");
}

The tracking error is happening further down in the bowels of the UserLib initially here on adding or removing roles:
private async Task<IdentityResult> RemoveUserFromRoles(
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
            ApplicationUser User,
            IList<string> RolesToRemove)
{
    try
    {
        IdentityResult result = IdentityResult.Success;
                foreach (string role in RolesToRemove)
                {
                    if (await userManager.IsInRoleAsync(User, role))
                    {
                        result = await userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(User, role);
                        if (!result.Succeeded) //If not successful the bail with the error
                        {
                            return result;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine( ex.Message );
                return IdentityResult.Failed(new IdentityError() { Code="Exception", Description=$"{ex.Message}"});
            }
        }

I am only using userManager here and as you can see for these functions, both the context and userMananger are passed in at the top (UpdateUser) function. The STRANGE thing is that when I call the same function from the controller. It doesn't happen and works fine.
For completeness the controller code is:
        public async Task<ActionResult<InfoBool>> UpdateUser(ApplicationUserDTO sentUserDTO)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
            // Get the logged in user.
            ApplicationUser loggedinUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User).ConfigureAwait(false);

            IList<string> roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(loggedinUser);
            bool userisadmin = false;
            if (roles.Contains(Enums.AllowedRoles.Administrator.ToString())) userisadmin = true;
            if (userisadmin || (sentUserDTO.Id == loggedinUser.Id)) // If the logged in user is an admin or the person edited then allow the update
            {
                return await _userlib.UpdateUser(_userManager, _context, sentUserDTO, sentUserDTO.Roles, userisadmin);
            }
            return Unauthorized();
        }

My guess is that the fact that I am using a contextFactory in the server side Service code means somehow that it is different from the context used by the userManager.
However, the context  in the controllers is just the standard one created in the program.cs at startup. What am I missing here?
EDIT (OTHER EDITS REMOVED TO AVOID CONFUSION)
Ok. After looking at the advice in the answers and comments, I have tried removing the context and userManager from the calling code - so the UserService code now looks like this:
        public async Task<ApplicationUserDTO> UpdateUser(ApplicationUserDTO user)
        {
            //using var _dbContext = _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext();   **COMMENTED OUT - REMOVED**
            bool updatingcurrrentuser = false;
            if (user.Id == CurrentUser.Id) updatingcurrrentuser = true;
            InfoBool? result = new();
            ApplicationUser? loggedinUser = await _userLib.GetLoggedInUser();
            bool userisAdmin = false;
            if((await _userLib.LoggedInUserIsAdminAsync()).Success) userisAdmin = true;
            if (userisAdmin || (user.Id == loggedinUser.Id)) // If the logged in user is an admin or the person edited then allow the update
            {
                result = await _userLib.UpdateUser(/*_userManager, *//*_dbContext,*/ user, user.Roles, userisAdmin);
            }
            if (result.Success)
            {
... more stuff

The UpdateUser function in the DAL now looks like this:
        public async Task<InfoBool> UpdateUser(
            //UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, **NOT PASSED IN**
            //RGDbContext context,
            ApplicationUserDTO user,
            List<string> Roles = null,
            bool userisadmin = false
            )
        {
            using var _dbContext = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext();

            //First check if its there ** NOT TRACKED **

            ApplicationUser? founduser = await _dbContext.Users.AsNoTracking().Include(x => x.Address)
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.UserName == user.UserName);
            if (founduser == null)
            {
                return new InfoBool(false, "User to update not found");
            }
            if (founduser.Address != null && user.Address != null && user.Address.Id == 0)
            { // If there is an address but the client sends it with a zero id  - to detect a client error
                return new InfoBool(false, "Address Id mismatch Error");
            }
            _mapper.Map(user, founduser);
            _mapper.Map(user.Address, founduser.Address);

            _dbContext.Entry(founduser).State = EntityState.Modified;
            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            _dbContext.Dispose();

            IList<string> currentroles = await GetRolesAsync(founduser.Id);
            // First check for changed roles
            
            List<string> newrolestoadd = Roles.Except(currentroles).ToList(); // Creates a list of the roles in Roles to add not in current roles
           
            List<string> rolestoremove = currentroles.Except(Roles).ToList(); // Create a list of the roles in current roles to remove not in roles
            if (newrolestoadd.Count() > 0) // There are some 
            {
                // If a player role has been added
                if (!currentroles.Contains(Enums.AllowedRoles.Player.ToString())
                    && Roles.Contains(Enums.AllowedRoles.Player.ToString()))
                {
                    founduser.IsPlayer = true;
                }
                if (!userisadmin && newrolestoadd.Contains(Enums.AllowedRoles.Administrator.ToString()))
                { //Just a check that any user adding an adminrole is already an admin
                    newrolestoadd.Remove(Enums.AllowedRoles.Administrator.ToString()); //Not allowed
                    //***TODO Add a log record here to indicate a possible security risk
                }
               // await AddUsertoRoles(userManager, founduser, newrolestoadd);
            }
            // Remove roles
            if (rolestoremove.Count() > 0)
            {
                if (!userisadmin && rolestoremove.Contains(Enums.AllowedRoles.Administrator.ToString()))
                {   // Only an admin can remove an admin
                    rolestoremove.Remove(Enums.AllowedRoles.Administrator.ToString());
                }
                await RemoveUserFromRoles( founduser, rolestoremove);
            }

Completely over the top probably (disposing of the context but to prove the point)
The RemoveUserFromRoles (which is the one I am testing and have temporarily commented out the add function) - now looks like this:
    private async Task<IdentityResult> RemoveUserFromRoles(
       // UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        ApplicationUser User,
        IList<string> RolesToRemove
        )
    {
        try
        {
            IdentityResult result = IdentityResult.Failed();

            foreach (string role in RolesToRemove)
            {
                if (await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(User, role))
                {
                    result = await _userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(User, role);
                    if (!result.Succeeded) //If not successful the bail with the error
                    {
                        return result;
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine( ex.Message );
            return IdentityResult.Failed(new IdentityError() { Code="Exception", Description=$"{ex.Message}"});
        }
    }

The user manager is no longer passed in but injected into the lib in the usual way.
Also, just in case, I have chenged the GetRolesAsync private function in the lib to just use the userManager.
        private async Task<List<string>> GetRolesAsync(/*RGDbContext context, string userID*/ ApplicationUser user)
        {
            //using var _context = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext();
            //List<string> roles = new List<string>();
            //var rolelist = await _context.UserRoles.AsNoTracking().Where(r => r.UserId == userID).ToListAsync();
            //foreach (var role in rolelist)
            //{
            //    var foundrole = await _context.Roles.FindAsync(role.RoleId); 
            //    if (foundrole != null && foundrole.Name != null) roles.Add(foundrole.Name);
            //}
            //return roles;
            var roles = (List<string>) await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
            return roles;
        }

For completeness the GetLoggedInUser function now looks like this:
        public async Task<ApplicationUser> GetLoggedInUser()
        {
            using var _context = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext();
            var claimslist = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Claims.ToList();
            string userId = claimslist.Find(x => x.Type.EndsWith("nameidentifier")).Value;
            ApplicationUser? user = await _context.Users.AsNoTracking().Where(u => u.Id == userId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            if (user == null) return null;
            foreach (var claim in claimslist)
            {
                if (claim.Type.EndsWith("role"))
                {
                    user.Roles.Add(claim.Value);
                }
            }
            return user;
        }

Sorry for the complex edit but I wanted to show all the changes. Suffice to say the error is still there. The only up/downside  is that the error also occurs when called from the controller now as well.. so it feels like I am going backwards.

GetLoggedInUser this is the cause I guess. Because you reterieeved the ApplicationUser twice within the same context. You can do AsNoTracking() for one of them or just initiate a scoped context aka using(var context ....)

Thanks @iSR5 - have added that in as an edit. I already detached it after the find .. at least I think I did. Should that not do it?.  Hard to find an element without tracking as detailed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34967116/how-to-combine-find-and-asnotracking

Nope just do context.Users.AsNoTracking().FindAsync and remove the detachment line.

or call it within  a using(var context = new Context()) scope, so you use different context than the current one.

Loading an ApplicationUser, updating an ApplicationUser from a DTO, saving the ApplicationUser... you need to be more pedantic about which internal methods have these responsibilities. Which also makes it easier to write unit tests, as you don't need a database to test the update method.

In your code you open a DbContext in UpdateUser which lives for the lifetime of the method.  You then start passing it around - _userLib.GetLoggedInUser and _userLib.UpdateUser.
Within UpdateUser you call UserManager to RemoveUserFromRoles.  It tries to open the same tables that are current open with tracking.  That's where you get your error.
Why does the controller work?  Don't know, but there's no indication of where _context comes from.  It's probably a single context shared by the application.
How to solve?  Sort out your logic and restructure the code.
Don't pass DbContexts around. Treat them as transactional: open and close within a method.
In UpdateUser open and close a context with tracking turned off to read in the user.
In your _userLib methods do the same.
In _userLib.UpdateUser open, update and close the context before calling the UserManager methods.
public async Task<InfoBool> UpdateUser(..)
{
    // Get A DbContext - no tracking 

    // First check if its there
    ApplicationUser? founduser = await context.Users
                                              .Include(x => x.Address)
                                              //.Include(x => x.Player)  // Don't need the player
                                              //.ThenInclude(y => y.Coins)
                                              .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.UserName == user.UserName);

    // Close the context

    if (founduser == null)
    {
        return new InfoBool(false, "User to update not found");
    }

    //....
    //Do the roles stuff
}


Thanks for the help, I have done a bunch of changes that I think should address what you suggest and put them in the edits above, still getting the error sadly. I keep coming back to the usermanager context.

I (think) I've got to the bottom of it... It requires using the UserManager to actually get the user in the method rather than passing it in. I'll put more up tomorrow, but wanted to stop you or anyone potentially wasting time. Thanks again...
