# Can I exclude an update on a object in entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an object in my entity model ( it is a view in the db getting data over a linked server). Anyways, when I call contex.savechanges(), it updates everything that is changed in the object model. I don't want to update that certain object. Is there a way to exclude that object from updating? I haven't been able to find any properties or methods that would work.

Thanks for any suggestions.
Brian

Comment: Did you try fetching the objects with `AsNoTracking`?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1162162/1370166).  You really want to not track this object.

Comment: I tried to use this, however there wasn't a method listed for it in the shortcut menu. Not sure if I have the correct version of entity framework or not.

Answer (score 1):

Set the object's state to `Unchanged`:

```
_context.Entry(myObject).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```

MSDN docs for:

[DbContext.Entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696578.aspx) method

[EntityState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.dataclasses.entityobject.entitystate.aspx) property

Comment: Sorry, but this is a hack that may cause issues later in code.  You are effectively lying to the framework to fool it into thinking no update is needed.

Comment: I couldn't find this option under the methods shortcuts.

Comment: What version of EF are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a class to use. Instead of changing things in the entity object, I just populated the object to use in the method. Works like a champ.